# How many ways to do choose $\leq 10$ from $5$ sets of $30$ objects.

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I have $5$ sets of letters each of size $30$ each. More specifically I have thirty

'a's,'b's,'c's,'d's and 'e's.

How many ways can I choose to paint $10$ or less of them?

So I seem to have $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 \leq 10$, $x_i \in \mathbb{N}$

Set $x_1 \leq x_2 \leq x_3 \leq x_4 \leq x_5$

Is this the correct starting direction?

Comment: I don't understand where the fact they come in 5 sets matters? would it be the same if the 150 objects came together?

Comment: @JorgeFernández I believe not, I think any of the same letter are equivelent, but we have number of solutions where 10 or less is filled by combinations of any of the letters.

Answer (score 2):

**Outline:** We assume that the $30$ objects in each group are identical.

The following is a useful trick. The number of non-negative integer solutions of $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5\le 10$ is the number of non-negative integer solutions of $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5+x_6=10$.

The second problem  is a standard one, solved using ["Stars and Bars."](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29)

Since $10$ is less than $31$, the constraint $x_i\le 30$ makes no difference.

**Edit:** We give a quick informal proof of the validity of the trick. I have $10$ candies, and want to give out $10$ **or fewer** of them to $5$ kids. The number of ways to do this is the number of solutions of $x_1+\cdots+x_5\le 10$.

Suppose we give any candies leftover from the $10$ to me. So effectively, we are distributing $10$ candies between $6$ "kids," one of them somewhat overaged. The number of ways to do this is the number of solutions of $x_1+\cdots+x_5+x_6=10$.

Somewhat more formally, there is a bijection between the distributions of $10$ or fewer to $5$ kids and the distributions of exactly $10$ to $6$ kids.

Comment: That's pretty cool! Why does that work though? Proof please?

Comment: Am I to interpret the question as two different a's $a_1$ and $a_2$ being different too $a_3$ and $a_4$?(I mean based on how common this sort of question is, I know this is subjective)

Comment: @900sit-upsaday: I made the standard interpretation. OP confirmed in an edit, when the (multi)sets were described as $30$ a's, $30$ b's, and so on.

Comment: @recursiverecursion: I have added a proof, using the particular numbers of the question. But the argument is general. The number of non-negative integer solutions of $x_1+\cdots+x_n\le K$ is the number of solutions of $x_1+\cdots+x_n+x_{n+1}=K$.

Comment: So the answer is just $\begin{pmatrix} 10\\5\end{pmatrix}=252$. Ten stars, and 5 bars.

Comment: If we are using one of the standard formulas, the answer is $\binom{10+6-1}{6-1}$ or equivalently $\binom{10+6-1}{10}$. The Wikipedia article does a pretty good job of explaining why.

Comment: About your earlier comment, maybe you are assuming that at least one of each letter is chosen. That condition does not seem to be asked for in the problem.